# Python and Mac memory. Security of sensitive data

Tags: python, macos, memory, ram

I have written a short Python script that generates random numbers and uses the [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) word [list](http://world.std.com/%7Ereinhold/dicewarewordlist.pdf) to create passphrases. Since the output of my script is plain text, I am wondering if it is secure. Mac OSX uses encrypted Virtual Memory, and I assume RAM is cleared when my machine is restarted. Will my plain-text passphrase persist anywhere on my Mac if I restart after creating it?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but the Diceware website [says](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/dicewarefaq.html#electronic) you shouldn't use a computer to generate random numbers for this use.

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd Yes. I am aware of that. I think the concern is that random number generators are not really random. To me, that is a "perfect is the enemy of the good" issue. I think `random.SystemRandom()` should serve well enough. Am I wrong? It saves me from pulling out the Yahtzee dice (the author of Diceware also recommends casino dice so I am really going rogue).